# Why Bundle in Intent get lost?

Tags: android, android-intent, kotlin, android-bundle

I have a `Serializable` SpecialObject with some parameters (Location etc. in turn `Serializable` as well)

I would like to open a Fragment (`MySpecialFragment`) by an Activity (`MySpecialActivity`) by handling over a `SpecialObject` object. It works so far, I can trigger and open the `MySpecialFragment` but the `SpecialObject` is not handled over properly. I feel like I can't see the forest for the trees.

Debugging it:

```
val PARAM_BUNDLE = "bundle_extra"
val PARAM_SPECIAL_EXTRA = "special_bundle_extra"

class MySpecialActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my_special)

    val sameIntentSht = intent // same as getIntent()

    val extras = intent.extras // same as getIntent().getExtras()
    val bundleExtras = intent.getBundleExtra(PARAM_BUNDLE)

    val extras2 = sameIntentSht.extras
    val bundleExtras2 = sameIntentSht.getBundleExtra(PARAM_BUNDLE)

    if(extras != null && extras2 != null && bundleExtras != null && bundleExtras2 != null) Timber.d("Jzst for debugging")

    FragmentHelper.inflateFragment(this, R.id.fragmentContainer, MySpecialFragment::class.java, extras)
}

companion object {
    fun createIntent(context: Context,
                     mySpecial: MySpecialObject?): Intent {
        val intent = Intent(context, MySpecialActivity::class.java)
        val bundle = Bundle()
        mySpecial?.let {
            bundle.putSerializable(PARAM_SPECIAL_EXTRA, mySpecial)
        }

        intent.putExtra(PARAM_BUNDLE, bundle)
        // intent.flags = FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
        return intent
    }
}
}
```

**Instantiation createIntent()**: Creating the Intent to launch the MySpecialActivity the `createIntent()` method works fine. When I [image: debug] into the intent object it has its bundle and that in turn has the Serializable MySpecialObject object.

**Unpacking the Bundle onCreate()**: As you can see in the [image: onCreate()] all the extra* and bundleExtra* objects don't have mMap

And the getExtras() directly from getIntent() (in Kotlin *intent.extras*)
is not the same extras as sameIntentSht which is obviously the same `val sameIntentSht = intent` . You see in the debug intent.extras has 652 bytes and sameIntentSht.extras has 604 bytes !??!?

**How can I handle over this bundle properly?**

EDIT: 
I used RubenGees suggestion. Works so far:

```
val intent = Intent(context, MySpecialActivity::class.java)
mySpecial?.let {
    intent.putExtra(PARAM_SPECIAL_EXTRA, mySpecial)
}
// intent.flags = FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
return intent
```

But on the onCreate I had to copy the intent into sameIntentsht anyway:  [image: see here] see `mMap` of `extra` and `extra2` !?

Comment: Why don't you call `intent.putExtra()` directly with your `Serializable` Object? There is a overload for it and that would avoid the construction of the `Bundle`.

Comment: Thnx, worked so far, see EDIT section.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what is going on there, but doesn't `intent.getSerializableExtra(PARAM_SPECIAL_EXTRA) as MySpecialObject` work? (Since the intent may not contain the extra, you should also check `intent.hasExtra(PARAM_SPECIAL_EXTRA`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of things:

- in the original code you're creating a Bundle containing a Bundle, and put that in the Intent. Thus you have one Bundle that's not really necessary. You can call `putExtra` directly on the Intent.
- Calling `intent.extras`, or `intent.getExtras()` *creates a copy of the extras bundle*. So this is expected that you get two different bundles.
- It is expected that when you debug, `extras` has empty `mMap`. Bundle has lazy semantics, and only the first call accessing the data will unparcel it, thus populating `mMap`.

I'd guess that initally you were creating an Intent containing a Bundle containing a Bundle, but when accessing you were trying to skip one step. I recommend deleting existing code and starting over:

- creating Intent and putting special data using `intent.putExtra(EXTRA_SPECIAL, specialObject)` method;
- and then retrieving special data by calling `intent.getSerializableExtra(EXTRA_SPECIAL)`.

This is everything that's needed here.